# Want to divide this div into three equal columns so that list data will look like 3 table

Tags: html, css, angular

i am printing a list data coming in observable format. I want ti divide screen into 3 similar columns so it looks like a table.
But each cell is not occupying same length so its not aligning properly.

```
 <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header main-header">
                        <h3 style="text-align: center;font-weight: 600;">Roles</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span class="list-column">RoleName</span>

                        <span class="list-column">Description</span>

                        <span class="list-column">Action</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li *ngFor="let item of userRoles; let i = index">
                            <span class="list-item">{{item.roleName}}</span>
                            <span class="list-item">{{item.roleDesc}}</span>
                            <span class="list-item">
                                <!-- <i class='fas fa-edit' style='font-size:24px'></i> -->
                                <a href="">Edit</a> /
                                <a href="">Delete</a> /

                            </span>
                        </li>
                        <br />
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

style.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.list-column {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 140px;
}

.list-item {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 140px;
  align-items: center;
}


.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want a table like layout, look into CSS-Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a table-like looking container I would suggest to use the following style:

```
.card{
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  display: grid;
}
```

This will divide card child elements to groups of 3 in the same size.

lET that the first column with have 50% width of the entire width you can do:

```
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Comment: thanks you so much. This solve my problem very precisely.

Comment: No problem :) Please mark the answer as a solution for future reference.

Comment: I accepted and upvoted it.
 answer as a solution for future reference, don't know how to do.